# how to send form data to mail ID

Tags: php, forms, email

Can someone please help me to find what is wrong with the code? Actually I am trying to send form data directly to mail Id, but the following code is not working.  I need to send all the user input data to mail Id in tabular format.

HTML part

```
<div class="form-group">
 <label class="control-label col-lg-2" for="Patient">Patient:</label>
  <div class="col-lg-10">
   <input type="text" class="form-control fc" name="patient" id="Patient">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
 <label class="control-label col-lg-2" for="Date">Date:</label>
  <div class="col-lg-10">          
   <input type="date" class="form-control fc" name= "date" id="Date">
  </div>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" data-loading-text="Sending...">Send</button>
```

PHP

```
function test_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}

$userinput==true; // set trigger for verification

//Error variables 
$patientErr1="";
$patientErr2="";
$DateErr = "";
$DoctErr = "";
$patient = $_POST["patient"];
$date = $_POST["date"];
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    if(empty($patient)){
        $patientErr1 = "You have to provide Name";
        $userinput = false;
    }
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$patient)){
        $patientErr2 = "You can't provide numeric value in name field";
        $userinput = false;
    }else{
        $patient = test_input($patient);
    }

    if (empty($date)){
        $DateErr = "Please select date";
        $userinput = false;

    }else{
        $date = test_input($date);
    }
    if(empty($doctor)){
        $DoctErr = "Please fill Doct Name";
        $userinput = false;
    }
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$doctor)){
        $DoctErr2 = "You can't provide numeric value in name field";
        $userinput = false;
    }else{
        $patient = test_input($doctor);
    }

if ($userinput == true ){

    // mail will sent to 
    $to = "test12345@gmail.com";
    $subject = "User input";
    $message = "
    ?>
    <html>
        <head>
        </head>
        <body>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Field Name</th>
                    <th>Value</th> 
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>patient Name</td>
                    <td><?php echo $patient; ?></td> 
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>date</td>
                    <td><?php echo $doctor; ?></td> 
                </tr>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
    <?php";
}
    //send mail
    mail($to,$subject,$message);
?>
```

Comment: mail accepts 4 arguments . `$headers` is missing try to find and use that other wise your code seems ok

Comment: i have see some mistake ' $message = "?>  ...  <?php  ";' in $message varable

Comment: @ M A SIDDIQUI  headers is optional ...

Comment: @MASIDDIQUI the 4th argument is not mandatory

Answer (score 0):

if you want to send email in html format using php mail() function then you need to set the headers and set content type to html.

There are lot of issues within your script, your php have _POSTs that you don't have in your form, I have re done your entire script. Please check mine against yours and see were you went wrong then learn from it.

Thanks :)

```
<?php



$errors = "";
; // check number of errors

//Error variables 
$patientErr1 = "";
$DateErr     = "";
$DoctErr     = "";
$emailErr    = "";


$DoneMessage = "";
$to          = "test12345@gmail.com";
$subject     = "User input";

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {


    if (empty($_POST['patient'])) {

        $patientErr1 = "You have to provide Name";
        $errors++;
    } else {

        $patient = test_input($_POST['patient']);

        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $patient)) {

            $patientErr1 = "You can't provide numeric value in name field";
            $errors++;
        }
    }

    if (empty($_POST['date'])) {

        $DateErr = "Please select date";
        $errors++;
    } else {

        $date = test_input($_POST['date']);
    }

    if (empty($_POST['email'])) {

        $emailErr = "enter email";
        $errors++;
    } else {

        $email = test_input($_POST['email']);

        if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email)) {

            $emailErr = "Enter valid email";
        }
    }


    if ($errors > 0) {

        // We have errors print them back

        $DoneMessage = "Please fix " . $errors . " below to send message";
    } else {
        // No Errors set headers and send email

        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n"; // set html
        $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'From: ' . $patient . ' <' . $email . '>' . "\r\n";


        $message = "<table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Patient Name</th>
                        <th>Value</th>
                        <th>Email</th>

                    </tr>";
        $message .= "<tr>

                             <td>$patient</td> 

                    </tr>";
        $message .= "<tr>
                        <
                        <td>$date</td> 

                    </tr>";

        $message .= "<tr>

                        <td>$email</td> 

                    </tr>";

        $message . "=     </table>";

        if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {

            $DoneMessage = "Thaks email sent";
        } else {

            $DoneMessage = "Server problem could not send email";
        }
    }



    // mail will sent to 




}



function test_input($data)
{
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}



?>

    <?php echo $DoneMessage;?>

<form method="POST" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-lg-2" for="Patient">Patient: <?php echo $patientErr1;?></label>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control fc" name="patient" id="Patient">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-lg-2" for="Date">Date: <?php echo $DateErr;?></label>
        <div class="col-lg-10">          
            <input type="date" class="form-control fc" name= "date" id="Date">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-lg-2" for="email">Your email: <?php echo $emailErr;?></label>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
            <input type="email" class="form-control fc" name="email" id="email">
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default" data-loading-text="Sending...">Send</button> 
</form>
```